# Sitelinks Search Box JSON-LD giving error on Google Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, json-ld

I implemented Google’s [Sitelinks Search Box](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) to my site. It was working very well. But today I cheked again on [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) and something was wrong. Now I’m getting below error:

> [image: Google Structured Data Testing Tool: 2 Errors for WebSite]

And my implementation is:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://www.saatler.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://www.saatler.com/arama?ara={search_term_string}",
    "query-input":"required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>
```

When I check the JSON on [the JSON-LD playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/index.html) everything is looking good. I didn’t change anything on my site. Is Google wrong about this issue? Or the Schema.org structure has changed? What should I do to fix these 2 problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that even the examples on the online [documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) receive the same exact error you received. When I changed

```
"@context": "http://schema.org"
```

to

```
"@context": "http://schema.org/true"
```

the error disappeared. Hope this helps.

[image]

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/true",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://www.saatler.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://www.saatler.com/arama?ara={search_term_string}",
    "query-input":"required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am getting the same error, but am using microdata - Any thoughts?

Comment: @skeetarian change http://schema.org/ to http://schema.org/true on your microdata

Comment: @hakkikonu - Thanks!

I switched to the LD JSON option but now am wondering why it now says "http"//www.example.com/WebSite" instead of just "WebSite"

I noticed that when I use the /true option it allows me to use "logo", but without it the "logo" is disallowed for WebSite.

This is turning out to be quite the hornets nest...

Comment: @hakkikonu and Franco: By using a different `@context` URI, you are no longer using the Schema.org vocabulary.

Comment: I believe you should accept my answer as the correct one as this one, while getting the Google good checkmark, does so for an incorrect @context and may cause others to implement an incorrect 'fix'.  :)

Comment: The page http://schema.org/true  doesn't exist. What's the point in changing it?

Answer (score 12):

Found the answer by reviewing the [schema.org Potential Actions page](http://schema.org/docs/actions.html).

Apparently, for whatever reason, Google’s [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) doesn’t like our short-hand version for textual representations of input and output.

When I switched to the verbose version I get the good checkmark for `WebSite` (1), not `http://www.example.com/Website` (1).

> **Textual representations of Input and Output**
>
> For convenience, we also support a textual short-hand for both of
>   these types that is formatted and named similarly to how they would
>   appear in their HTML equivalent. For example:
>
> ```
> "<property>-input": {
>   "@type": "PropertyValueSpecification",
>   "valueRequired": true,
>   "valueMaxlength": 100,
>   "valueName": "q"
> }
> ```
>
> Can also be expressed as:
>
> ```
> <property>-input: "required maxlength=100 name=q"
> ```

Here is our full code for anyone else trying to follow this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{

  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "name" : "Example Company",
  "url": "http://www.example.com/",
  "sameAs" : [ "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Example/###############",
    "https://plus.google.com/b/#####################/#####################"],
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "http://www.example.com/search/results/?q={q}",
    "query-input": {
        "@type": "PropertyValueSpecification",
        "valueRequired": true,
        "valueMaxlength": 100,
        "valueName": "q"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @unor Thanks for the edit - I was having the hardest time getting the formatting right here...  :)

Answer (score 2):

It [was a bug](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/8jN5M7UHkEU/wNZr_VvN1TcJ) in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

It’s fixed now: the tool reports no more errors for your markup.