# Enabling Google Sitelinks Search Box

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, json-ld

I want to enable **Google Sitelinks Search Box** for a website. The point is its custom search page is implemented by hash fragment so the JSON-LD data snippet is like this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "name" : "my site",
  "alternateName" : "example.com",
  "url": "http://www.example.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "http://www.example.com/Search/#!/Keyword-{search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>
```

While Google tries to extract the information from this part `"required name=search_term_string"` to show the sitelinks search box, encounter a problem:

```
:   http://schema.org/True
valueName:  missing and required
```

I suspect maybe Google just expect search string inside a **query string** instead of **hash fragment**, what do you recommend except redirecting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sitelinks Search Box JSON-LD giving error on Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780247/sitelinks-search-box-json-ld-giving-error-on-google-structured-data-testing-tool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @unor I found the solution, so the final code is something like this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "WebSite",
          "name" : "example",
          "alternateName" : "example.com",
          "url": "http://www.example.com/",
          "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "SearchAction",
            "target": "http://www.example.com/Search/#!/Keyword-{search_term_string}/",
            "query-input": {
          "@type": "PropertyValueSpecification",
          "valueRequired": true,
          "valueMaxlength": 100,
          "valueName": "search_term_string"
      }
          }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for post solution

Comment: @Waki and HosseinBakhtiari: note that [it was a bug in Google’s Testing Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31145753/1591669), which is now fixed. So the original markup seems to work again.

Comment: Thanks @unor, by the way how much it takes for Google to respond to this change and show it inside SERP for a high traffic website(10'000 concurrent users)?